# What were normal bathing habits in Cairo in 1798?

Tags: cultural-history, middle-east, modern

In the old western world we did not bath much after the fall of the Roman Empire. I was wondering if that is the same for the population in Egypt in around 1798. This leads me to 2 questions

1) Did the people in Cairo cultivated bath in the same way as the Romans and did they had big swimming pools as the Romans ?

2) I read that the population in Cairo was about 350 000. Is it fair to say that Cairo was the biggest city in the Arab World at that time and even today? I can't find an Arab city with a larger number of population.

Comment: Your premise is already flawed, as a 5 minute googling about medi-eval bathing habits in Europe would tell you. Just because they didn't spend hours a day in the Caracallan Baths (which we don't either nowadays), doesn't mean they didn't understand the need for hygiene more frequent than the purported extreme case of some monk bathing once a year at Easter.

Comment: Christians had an impact on the bathing habits I know for sure - the Christians did not like many of the Roman habits. So as I said how was it in Egypt which was mostly Islamic rather than Christian. Did they fe have a Caracallan Bath in Cairo?

Comment: Maybe this link is helpful https://www.1843magazine.com/features/photo-essay/cairos-last-baths or this http://www.dailynewsegypt.com/2012/10/11/the-ancient-tradition-of-cairos-bath-houses/

Comment: 1798 is not normally considered medieval.... but the question would benefit from research.